# Deploy with git to dokku on digitalocean

Tags: node.js, git, dokku

I' trying to push my first app on digitalocean with git. on the server there is an instance of dokku installed.

I tried [this Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-install-image-to-deploy-your-app) but when I try `git push dokku master`, it says:

```
fatal: 'testapp' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: some nice guy gave me a hint:
$ cat /c/users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@[serverIP] "sudo sshcomm
and acl-add dokku [aRandomWord]"

and now it works! maybe someone is there, who can explain what this command does? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command:

```
$ cat /c/users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@[serverIP] "sudo sshcomm and acl-add dokku [aRandomWord]"
```